# Code Error is :- "Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, null-check

Error Code
[image]

I have tried many condition for the Null check Operator but I couldn't find any solution regarding the Null check Operator.

I want to Insert the data onto Sqlite Database that i have Created Named "LocalDatabase".
When i Click Login Button then I want to push data from one screen to another with the help of the database.

Please, Give me the Solution that How can i Transfer the data from one Screen to another using Sqlite database. and How can i Remove the null check Operator Error.

Comment: initallocaldbms is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

#### Working solution

- So, the instructions after your `if statement` is executed `whenever localdb is null or not`
- The easist way to go about this is simply adding these instruction inside a `else` bloc.
- Just like so

```dart
Future<Database> get getlocaldbms async {
  if(localdbms != null) {
    return localdbms;
  }

//TODO: ADD THIS BLOC TO FIX THE ERROR
  else{
   localdbms = await initlocaldbms();
   return localdbms;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can't Fix the Error Bro.

Comment: These Method Didn't work.